# probabilistic problem in convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, means

Let $A_n$ denote the probability of a car not working on day n. Suppose $A_n=0$ mean car doesn't work and $A_n=1$ means car works, If $A_n$ converges to 1 in $\mathbb{P}$,where $\mathbb{P}$ is a probability measure. How frequent (often) do we have $A_n=0$?

This question quite frankly makes little sense to me. How do we have convergence in measure when we don't have a random variable involved? Are we supposed to implicitly assume a random variable is being used? Also, what does it mean "how often (or synonymously, frequent; as used in lecture notes) do we have a probability $A_n$? Im not sure how to tackle the problem

Comment: Car failing on day n is the random variable.

Comment: @herbsteinberg what would be the sigma algebra in this case?

Comment: Is that the complete question? And is $A_n$ actually the *probability* of the car failing *on* the day $n$? Because as it stands, the answer is "for finitely many $n$" and has nothing to do with probability

Comment: @G.Chiusole i just edited

Comment: Car failing on day n is elementary event (random variable).  Get sigma algebra by usual rule (countable combinations generated bt elementary events).

Comment: @herb steinberg may you write a complete solution please? :)

Comment: Your definition of $A_n$ is contradictory. If $A_n$ is the probability that the car will fail, then $A_n = 0$ means that the car will work with $100\%$ certainty, and $A_n =1$ means the car will fail with $100\%$ certainty. You are not free to then declare them to mean the opposite.

Comment: I am not sure what you need.  Just check Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra